# Find the value b, such that the line intersects the parabola only once

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = 3x^2+5x+7$ and $g(x)=bx+3$ find "b" such that $g(x)$ intersects $f(x)$ only once.

I have tried setting them equal to each other than solving for x but I end up using the quadratic formula with imaginary values. I though maybe using the vertex of the parabola to figure out what transformation $g(x)$ would require but I am stuck.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to find $b$ such that the equation $3x^2+(5-b)x+4=0$ has exactly one solution. This will occur exactly if the discriminant is equal to zero i.e. $(5-b)^2-4(3)(4)=0$. Solve for $b$.